# How to get dynamic css layout like that:

Tags: css, layout

I am new to css and layouts and have problem with one layout

I am trying to develop an app in JS, but I would like to have this layout in pure css. Is it possible?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vxeqL/

My main problem is with blue box, as #left is 100% height, and #left-top has constant height: 200px;

[image]

My code co far (HTML):

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="container">

<div id="left">

    <div id="left-top"></div>
    <div id="left-bottom"></div>
</div>


<div id="right">
</div>


</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left:0;
}

div#left {
width: 600px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}

div#left-top {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}

div#left-bottom {
#width: ?;
#height: ?;
}

div#right {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
margin-left:600px;
}

div#footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to use a graphical editor like Layer Styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use just absolute positioning?
Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/hPpTV/

```
#header, #container, #left, #left-top, #left-bottom, #right, #footer {
    position: absolute;
}
#header {
    top:0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
}
#left {
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 300px;
}
#left-top {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#left-bottom {
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
#right {
    top:0;
    left: 300px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
 height:100%;
}
div#left {
width: 600px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}
div#left-top {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
div#left-bottom {
height:150px;
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}
div#left {
width:40%;
float:left;
height: 100%;
}
div#right {
width:60%;
height: 100%;
float:right;
}
div#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This will no work for me: I can't use percents in width as left panel must have 600px witth. And #left-bottom must fit to the rest (can't use 150px height)